# Request for member in something not a structure or union? DevC++

Tags: c, structure

I have the folowing code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX 419430400
#define CHR 50
#define INT 2000

FILE *doc;
char *path;


int BITE, LOOP;
int DOCUMENT[MAX];
int LENGTH = 0;


struct XmlNode {
    char Tags[CHR];
    char InnerText[INT];
    char Atributes[CHR];
};
typedef XmlNode;

void LoadXml (char _path[200]) {
    LOOP = 0;
    path = _path;
    doc = fopen(path,"r+");
    do {
        BITE = fgetc(doc);
        DOCUMENT[LOOP] = BITE;
        LOOP++;
    } while(!feof(doc));
    LENGTH = LOOP - 1;
}
void CloseXml (char _path[200]) {
    path = NULL;
    fclose(doc);
}
void SaveXml (char _path[200]) {
    LOOP = 0;
    FILE *save = fopen(_path,"w+");
    for (LOOP = 0; LOOP < LENGTH; LOOP++) {
        fprintf(save,"%c",(char)DOCUMENT[LOOP]);
    }
    fclose(save);
}
void PrintXml () {
    LOOP = 0;
    for (LOOP = 0; LOOP < LENGTH; LOOP++) {
        printf("%c",(char)DOCUMENT[LOOP]);
    }
}
void AppendChild(XmlNode _node, XmlNode _child)
{
    char _tagBeggin[CHR+2], _tagEnd[CHR+3];
    _tagBeggin[0] = '<';
    _tagEnd[0] = '<';
    _tagEnd[1] = '/';
    for (LOOP = 0; LOOP < strlen(_child->InnerText); LOOP++){

    }
}
```

The error apears at AppendChild procedure, in for or when ever i try to acces a value like: _child.InnerText, the same error.

```
Error: request for member 'InnerText' in something not a structure or union.
```

The program serves as homework. Idea is to make a program that works with xml files, for my own,not using any library. And i decided to make my one. So here is what i made.

AppendChild funcion should include an existing XmlNode to a new one.

Thank you for any help. :)

Comment: `typedef XmlNode;` should be typedef struct XmlNode XmlNode;

Comment: OMG. Thank you VoidPointer, just saved me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`typedef XmlNode;` should be

```
typedef struct XmlNode XmlNode; 
typedef XmlNode *XmlNodePtr;
```

Use pointer to structure always when sending to function, so modify function as,

```
void AppendChild(XmlNodePtr _node, XmlNodePtr _child)
```